# backbonejs beginners issue - fetching and displaying json data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Im new to Backbone (dont hate me) but am pulling my hair out trying to do a very simple thing.

Im loading a json file (correctly as I can see it loading in firebug) and I just want to pull some info from it purely for testing (as its my first backbone code)

However, I cant get this working and end up with one blank li tag (code below)

```
<ul id="phones"></ul>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.rc.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="foo" type="text/template">
        <li><%= name %></li>
    </script>

<script>

    var Phones = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url:'http://backbone.local/phones/phones.json'
    })
    var PhonesView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:'#phones',
        initialize:function(){
            this.collection = new Phones();
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.render();
        },
        template:_.template($('#foo').html()),
        render:function(){
                    var foo = this.collection.toJSON();
            $(this.el).html(this.template(foo));
            return this;
        }
    })
    var phonesView = new PhonesView();
</script>
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

**UPDATE 1**

I thought it may be due to fetch being async so i called render in success callback of fetch as below. The console.log fires fine but still no json data in rendered html (i also changed to using handlebars)

```
       <script>
        var Phones = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url:'http://backbone.local/phones/phones.json'
        })
        var PhonesView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el:'#phones',
            initialize:function(){
                var self = this;
                this.collection = new Phones();
                this.collection.fetch({
                    success:function(){
                        console.log('json loaded');
                        self.render();
                    }
                });
            },
            template: Handlebars.compile('<li>sdsadsadsadsad {{name}} dsfcdfd</li>'),
            render:function(){
                var foo = this.collection.toJSON();
                $(this.el).html(this.template(foo));
                return this;
            }
        })
        var phonesView = new PhonesView();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Handlebars, a collection template looks like this:

```
{{#items}} <li>  {{name}} </li> {{/items}}
```

You also need to wrap your collection JSON in an `items` object so that the Handlebars template can reference it as above:

```
var foo = { items: this.collection.toJSON() };
```

**Edit**

There's actually one more issue ... `collection.toJSON()` doesn't convert each model to JSON.  So you need to write:

```
this.collection.models.map(function(x) { return x.toJSON(); });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WEQdC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

On your view:

```
'initialize': function() {
    this.template = _.template('<p><% model.text $></p>');
    this.collection.fetch({error: function() { console.log(arguments); }, 'success': _.bind(this.onFetch,this) });
    return this;
},
'onFetch': function(collection) {
    this.collection.on("add", this.onAdd, this);          
    this.collection.each( _.bind(this.onAdd, this) );
    return this;
},
'onAdd': function(model){    
    //do something like:
    this.$el.find('.items').append(this.template({model: model}) ) 
);
```

Comment: Some explanation might be useful. Binding to `"add"` in `initialize` might make more sense, `fetch` triggers a `"reset"` event so binding to that rather than an explicit success handling would be more common. And you can supply a context argument to `each` so you don't need to create an extra function with `_.bind`:  `this.collection.each(this.onAdd, this)`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your explicit question of why you only get an empty li. You must send the template some name data. For example:

```
render:function(){
    var firstModel = this.collection.at(0);
    var firstName = firstModel.get("name");
    $(this.el).html(this.template({name: firstName}));
    return this;
}
```

Of course, the above code is only to understand what's missing, and not how a backbone application should be implemented. I really recommend that you go over the annotated TODO example linked from Backbone's website, and understand the basic patterns that are implemented there.

**Update based on your comment:**
Different ways of solving this. Really recommend reading: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

To continue on the "hacky path" of solving this so you can see something:

```
addOne: function(phone) {
    this.$el.append(this.template(phone.toJSON()));
    return this;
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(); //clear everything in the view
    this.collection.forEach(_.bind(this.addOne,this)); //Will call addOne for every model in the collection.
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Ta joholo, if i had a flat example like yours {name:'bob'} I can see bob get called into the HTML which is a great start. However, if I then try to parse in the JSON file like var foo = this.collection.toJSON(); $(this.el).html(this.template(foo)); it appears blank again. Any ideas? A console.log of foo shows me the JSON file as expected